# MySQL Many to Many select

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a MySQL Many to Many select query. I have three tables:

- Profiles
- Skills
- Profile_skills (Profile ID and Skills ID)

I want to be able to search for a skill (PHP for example) and all profiles with that skill show up in a list, but including all their other skills. Like most freelance sites, so I can also see that they know MySQL etc.

I haven't found or figured out the **correct** way to get all info about a profile including all their skills. This is my best result so far:

```
SELECT * FROM profiles INNER JOIN profile_skills ON 
profile_skills.profil_id = profiles.profil_id INNER JOIN skills ON
skills.skill_id = profile_skills.skill_id WHERE skill = 'PHP'
```

But this only gives me the profile with that one skill and not the rest.

Result: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YN7FI.jpg

Expected: 
To have the id, Skill "PHP", and the rest of skills, for example "C#" if user id 1 possesses that skill.
[http://imgur.com/5bCG4qo](https://imgur.com/5bCG4qo)

So like this when I search for a profile with a skill, it also shows the rest of that profiles acquired skills.

Comment: why group by ???

Comment: You can't do a GROUP BY and a SELECT *, I'm surprised that didn't error out.

Comment: you have skill ='PHP'   so you get only the data related  to this skill

Comment: Forget the group by, I was desperate. It was because it returned the profile twice because of two different skills before, I want it in one row if possible

Comment: @scaisEdge yes that's because people should be able to search profiles by skills, but I would like to show all their skills on the list of profiles with that skill that you searched for

Comment: update your question  .. add a proper data sample and the expected  result  please

Comment: Now that you changed your Query, update your question as this does NOT return a single row (GROUP BY did)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a sub query to identify the accounts, and then load details about them with the super query (and [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) the skills if you want). Something like:

```
SELECT profiles.*, GROUP_CONCAT(skills.skill SEPARATOR ', ') AS the_skillz
FROM profiles INNER JOIN profile_skills (...) INNER JOIN skills (...)
WHERE profiles.profile_id IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT profile_id 
  FROM profile_skills INNER JOIN skills (...) 
  WHERE skills.skill = 'PHP'
)
GROUP BY profiles.profile_id;
```

Comment: I tried this, but this returns two results, one with each skill. Are there no way to return both skills in the same line with his profile? So I don't get profile with ID returned as many times as he has skills?

Comment: You can use group concat (i edited answer) - this is mysql syntax, but most db engines have similar. For performance reasons I wouldn't do all this in one query. Just run one query to get the profile IDs that match, and then display them with whatever load/display logic you have that loads their data separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can re-join the `profile_skills` and `skills` table to get the result you want.

```sql
SELECT p.*, s2.*
FROM skills s1
INNER JOIN profile_skills ps1 ON s.skill_id = ps1.skill_id
INNER JOIN profiles p ON ps1.profil_id = p.profil_id
INNER JOIN profile_skills ps2 ON p.profil_id = ps2.profil_id
INNER JOIN skills s2 ON ps2.skill_id = s2.skill_id
WHERE s1.skill = 'PHP'
```

This will get you a result like this:

```
| p.id | p.name | s.id |       s.skill      |
---------------------------------------------
|  1   | rasmus |  1   |         PHP        |
|  1   | rasmus |  2   |        Linux       |
|  2   | thomas |  1   |         PHP        |
|  2   | thomas |  3   |  Eating Sandwiches |
```

There are various different ways to get each profile in one row with a list of skills. One way is with `GROUP_CONCAT` in MySQL.

```sql
SELECT p.profil_id, p.profile_name, GROUP_CONCAT(s2.skill) AS skills
FROM skills s1
INNER JOIN profile_skills ps1 ON s.skill_id = ps1.skill_id
INNER JOIN profiles p ON ps1.profil_id = p.profil_id
INNER JOIN profile_skills ps2 ON p.profil_id = ps2.profil_id
INNER JOIN skills s2 ON ps2.skill_id = s2.skill_id
WHERE s1.skill = 'PHP'
GROUP BY p.profil_id
```

I added the `profile_name` column for example, since I don't know what your columns actually are, and you can add other ones, or even still use `p.*`. Technically, the other columns in `profile` aren't defined with `GROUP BY p.profil_id`, and you generally shouldn't select columns that aren't either included in the grouping or some aggregate function, but MySQL will take care of that for you *in this case*, since they'll all have the same values for each row with the same `p.profil_id`.

Another way is to just use the first query and do the grouping in PHP:

```
$previous_id = null;
while ($row = some_fetch_method()) {
    if ($row['profil_id'] != $previous_id) {
        echo "<h3>$row[profile_name]</h3>";
    }
    echo "<div>$row[skill]</div>";
}
```

obviously the HTML won't be quite what you need, but it should be enough to show the general idea.